# Positioning elements within wordpress post

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add positioned images to a wordpress site and I'm really struggling to figure out how position elements within wordpress posts rather than absolute on the page. I've pen'd out what I'd like it to look like: http://codepen.io/Sovvyg/pen/grkvjX

```
<div class="fullcircle">
<img class="section" id="man" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-man-small1.png" />
<img class="section" id="section1" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-part1-small.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-part1-small-green.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-part1-small.png';" />|
<img class="section" id="section2" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-part2-small.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-part2-small-blue.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LSSI-hover-part2-small.png';" />
<img class="section" id="section3" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section3-small.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section3-small-red.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section3-small.png';" />
<img class="section" id="section4" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section4-small.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section4-small-turq.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section4-small.png';" />
<img class="section" id="section5" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section5-small.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section5-small-ppl.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section5-small.png';" />
<img class="section" id="section6" src="http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section6-small.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section6-small-orange.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://laurengrace.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/section6-small.png';" />
</div>
<style>
.fullcirlce {max-width: 100%; position:relative;}
.section {position: absolute}
#man {top: 295px; left: 125px;}
#section1 {top: 310px; left: 25px;}
#section2 {top: 189px; left: 14px;}
#section3 {top: 120px; left: 58px;}
#section4 {top: 120px; left: 204px;}
#section5 {top:190px; left: 255px;}
#section6 {top:310px; left:240px;}
```

but when I add it to wordpress it break the images up and stacks them, I've played around with my css but just cant get it right: http://laurengrace.uk/tester/

Any help would be appreciated, I'm really new to all this!

Thanks,
Lauren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to all your section css properties.

Edit;
For object to be inside the page, you need to calculate width/height and create space for the absolute elements.
After this you need to play with top/left properties.

```
.fullcircleparent{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 400px;
    top: -157px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats worked in a way, best ive got yet only now its below the page content and i want it to be inside it. any ideas? http://laurengrace.uk/tester/

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much totally got it to work! makes complete sense!

Comment: Could you choose this answer as answer of the post? Thanks Sovvyg